# Obtener dato de tag small de web jsoup java

Tags: java, jsoup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me pueden ayudar a obtener el valor del tag `<small>`? He intentado pero no he podido. Soy nuevo con esto del Jsoup.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para resolver el problema? Considera que, tal como luce la pregunta, estás pidiendo que te brinden el código hecho para resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resulta difícil saber que es lo que has probado y con qué has tenido problemas exactamente.

¿Estás usando jSoup para parsear el HTML como texto? o estás tratando de parsear la web directamente?

Con jSoup puedes conseguir el contenido de cualquier tag de múltiples maneras dado que el HTML puede recorrerse e inspeccionarse en un sinfín de posibilidades.

Lo más cómodo sueles ser tratar de buscar in **identificador único** que te acerque todo lo posible a tu tag, lo ideal sería que este tuviera un id o una clase css única y sería trivial localizarlo con una expresión xpath como similar a esta:

```
 //small[@id='UNIQUE_ID']/text()
```

Pero dado que no es así en tu caso, deberás buscar una estructura HTML que tan solo pueda darse para llegar a tu tag o buscar una combinación de atributos en tu tag o algún contenedor cercano. Algo similar a esto debería servir (**no lo he probado** dado que desconozco el código HTML o la web):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
Element small = doc.select("table[bgcolor=#E3E7F1][cellpadding=0]").select("small").first();
```

Lo  malo de este tipo de accesos es que tu código queda muy ligado a estos atributos que pueden variar fácilmente en el diseño HTML invalidando tu código.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. He intentado obtener todos los <td>. obtener el <td> identificando la tabla así como tu colocaste, he intentado obtener el <small> hijo del <td> y nada. Y lo necesito es parsear directamente de la web. Es el estado del toner de una impresora y ese modelo si me ha dado dolor de cabeza por su estructura de etiquetas.

Comment: Prueba poco a poco, partiendo de algún contenedor que si puedas recuperar, es decir, la tabla la puedes localizar correctamente? inspecciona el código debugando el resultado, quizás no reconozca debidamente la etiqueta y tengas que acceder manualmente al *child* que corresponda. Yo he tenido problemas puntuales si el HTML no está debidamente creado aunque parece que ese no es tu caso.